# Wrong arguments received from filtering xml get-winEvent

Tags: xml, powershell, logging, event-log

I am filtering event log fields(EventData) from the xml file and passing the values as parameter to a powershell script. Below is the values I am taking using value queries tag:-

```
<ValueQueries>
        <Value name="ServiceName">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='param1']</Value>
        <Value name="Status">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='param2']</Value>
        <Value name="eventID">Event/System/EventID</Value>
      </ValueQueries>
```

Below is the Event Data field from Event Log file

```
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">PW Service</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">stopped</Data> 
  <Binary>500057002F0031000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
```

This is how I am passing parameters to my script

```
 <Exec>
      <Command>Powershell.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Desktop\BatchScripting\PWDown.ps1 $(eventID) $(ServiceName) $(Status)</Arguments>
    </Exec>
```

Now when I pass the parameter to my script depending on the filter I have created it should give me as below:-

```
eventID=7036
ServiceName=PW Service
Status=Stopped
```

Instead, it gives me as below:-

```
eventID=7036
ServiceName=PW
Status=Service
```

> To add on, I suspect it is because of the (space) in "PW Service"
>   because when I changed the name of the service (param1 in eventData field) to "PW" in
>   event logs, then it gave me the correct results.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to put the Service name in double quotes while passing it. That will deal with the spaces in the service name.

Comment: It's funny how things so small can make such a huge difference . It worked.